# Will a partition based on part of ID pay off on S3 database?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

**My scenario**: I'm using a AWS S3 and GLUE for quite complex ETL process. Tables typically have personID and many unique properties. A single table can have a single or multiple rows per personID. **PersonID is a string of 100 alphanumeric characters**.

**The problem**:
There are a lot of joins based on personID. Which are really slow. Because of the use case I don't have any good field to create a partition.

**My idea**:
Create a partition based on a new column: first two letters of the personID or on a control number of personID.

**Question**:
Is it likely that partitioning will speed up the processes in my case? Does a pyspark code in a glue job utilize the fact that a join condition is based on partition? I will have to add extra condition on all the joins and extra column on all the tables.

Thanks!